# Button creates "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" in "<DOCTYPE html>"

Tags: javascript

When the button created below is pressed, it returns the following error:

"1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

in DOCTYPE html at the top of the html file.

```
function createButton(check){
    var btn = document.createElement("button"); 
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "function(){checkQuestion(check);}"); 
    var textbtn = document.createTextNode("Submit"); 
    btn.appendChild(textbtn);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

check is a variable that refers to a number that specifies a question, which is checked with checkQuestion().

Is the error from the code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onXYZ` attribute-style handlers are meant to be step-by-step code; the browser wraps them in a function. So that `onXYZ` handler ends up being something like this:

```
function onclick(event) {
    function() {
        checkQuestion(check);
    }
}
```

You can see the problem: The content of the generated function is invalid.

So if using an `onXYZ` handler, it should be:

```
btn.setAttribute("onclick", "return checkQuestion(check);");
```

...but note that `check` must be a **global** variable in that case.

Instead, you may want to assign to the `onclick` property instead:

```
btn.onclick = function() { return checkQuestion(check); };
```

...which allows it to work with the `check` that it closes over; in your case, the `check` that's the argument to your `createButton` function for the call generating the button.

Or use `addEventListener` unless legacy support (IE8 and earlier, including IE's [in]compatibility mode) is required:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    return checkQuestion(check);
}, false);
```